# Drawing on wxStaticBitmap?

Tags: c++, image-processing, wxwidgets

Is it possible in wxWidgets that a PaintDc event can draw on a wxStaticBitmap class and save it as another bitmap image?

Comment: I don't think it's possible sir. That's why it's called STATICBITMAP.

Comment: You could copy the static bitmap to a regular non-static bitmap, draw on that then save the resulting bitmap to another image.